# Image in the middle of a dl line/row, similar to what <td colspan=2 would do in a table

Tags: html, markup

EDIT: I have clarified more. I appreciate the first comment. I have previously read the faqs.

I have default MVC code that puts a `<dl><dt><dd>`, and instead of a dt and dd, I'm looking to show the image on the full row and not just on the "right column" or side of the list.

I'm not as familiar with dt/dd as compared to tr/td, so there's my confusion. If I add the img tag, it shows the image after Type and then the value of Type is pushed to another line - looks bad, and that's the problem at hand.

Example - Here ya go:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/J8tKrD
(look at the right panes only - other is default from their site)

I am not putting the image in a dt or dd, as then it would just be on the left or right. I understand that it's not valid markup either, hence the point of the post, hah.

Comment: I find it hard to visualise what you want. Can you post some more HTML? Preferably including the image you're talking about. And there is no such thing as `tr colspan=2`

Comment: Please, read **before** ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . This post is a good candidate to be closed

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude This still is a seasoned user, with 21 questions and a silver badge.

Comment: @MrLister it doesn't matter, if he don't know how to ask, he must to read slowly. Some people participate in stackoverflow without reading it NEVER. This is not a good asked question.

Comment: In spanish language, "me la suda que tenga medallitas, aprende a leer"

Comment: Guys, I meant <td colspan=2. easy mistake

Comment: Put your code inside it to  clarify  more

Comment: hi, java I don't use, but in general using `<dl>`, `<dt>` and `<dd>` is much the same as `<ul>` with `<li>` (but an extra bit under it. Basically, `<dl>` doesn't contain data, it just marks the start/end of the data definitons. `<dt>` always expects a line to itself (so does `<dd>`)  but you can fix them to force them online the same line as `display:inline` for instance.  
The equivalent to `<td>` spanning 2 columns is just `<dt>` (the `<dd>` can be skipped anytime you like, eg for headings. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using bootstrap.

In your case you just need to add `display:block` to your image.

```
<img src="1.jpg" style="display:block">
```